# out of memory Exception while set it from file

Tags: android

If i am setting the scale more than 1 then image is stretching and blurring or else it is giving out of memory exception. How to maintain image original quality without out of memory exception. This is my code

```
public Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=400;

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale=1;
            while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
              scale*=2;
            //scale*=2.5;

            System.gc();
            //Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at [link] (http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Answer (score 0):

Change your function like this

```
    public Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=100;

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale=1;
        while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
          scale*=2;
        //scale*=2.5;

        System.gc();
        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

Now From your on Create if u want to scale it then simply use

```
   Bitmap.createScaleBitmap(bitmap src,desired height,desired width,false);
```

store this in a new bitmap like

```
          Bitmap mynewbitmap =  Bitmap.createScaleBitmap(bitmap src,desired height,desired width,false);
```

Then set the image in ImageView.Like

```
             ImageView.setImageBitmap(mynewbitmap);
```

Note:- Remember one thing Bitmap DecodeFile function is created for getting the file from your memory so that we can load the image.If you dont use this and directly you want to scale your bitmap then you will get OutOfMemory error.So,The Algorithm should work like

1. First decode the file using Decode File function
2. use Required Size = 100 enough for this
3. Now use CreateScaleBitmap function to scale it according to your choice
4. set it into your ImageView

Comment: Confused where the 2 is coming from in the `o.outWidth/scale/2` and `o.outHeight/scale/2`. I removed this 2 and now it behaves how I expect, the scale increases until the width or height will be less than the REQUIRED_SIZE.

Answer (score 0):

This is a toughee.. You cannot be sure that the OOM is coming because of the written code only as it is cumulative heap memory that goes out of the allocated one.

I would suggest that you need to use Eclipse MAT tool to check for places where you have allocated memory (added bitmap's) in your code.

For every place you use Bitmaps don't forget to write Bitmap.recycle() as that will help you to garbage collect unused bitmaps giving your app more memory for new ones.